# How to add worklog to Jira Issue using REST API (NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api

I am creating an add-on which should create worklogs automatically. I am using node-js (jira-connector). 
I managed to get Issues, and to create new, but I am getting the error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing 'worklog' property
>   when I want to add worklogs to a Issue

```
   function updateIssueInJira()
    {
        var jira = getoAuth();

        try {
            return new Promise(() => {
                jira.issue.addWorkLog({
                    opts: { 
                        issueKey: 'NTS-4',
                        adjustEstimate: 'new',
                        newEstimade: '2d', 
                        worklog: 'Testing' 
                    } 
                })
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } 
    }
```

## The definition of addWorkLog is:

```
       /**
         * Adds a new worklog entry to an issue.
         *
         * @method addWorkLog
         * @memberOf IssueClient#
         * @param {Object} opts The options to pass to the API.  Note that this object must contain EITHER an issueId or
         *     issueKey property; issueId will be used over issueKey if both are present.
         * @param {string} [opts.issueId] The id of the issue.  EX: 10002
         * @param {string} [opts.issueKey] The Key of the issue.  EX: JWR-3
         * @param {string} [opts.adjustEstimate] Allows you to provide specific instructions to update the remaining time
         *     estimate of the issue. Valid values are
         *     * "new" - sets the estimate to a specific value
         *     * "leave"- leaves the estimate as is
         *     * "manual" - specify a specific amount to increase remaining estimate by
         *     * "auto"- Default option. Will automatically adjust the value based on the
         *          new timeSpent specified on the worklog
         * @param {string} [opts.newEstimate] (required when "new" is selected for adjustEstimate) the new value for the
         *     remaining estimate field. e.g. "2d"
         * @param {string} [opts.reduceBy] (required when "manual" is selected for adjustEstimate) the amount to reduce the
         *     remaining estimate by e.g. "2d"
         * @param {Object} opts.worklog See {@link: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e1106}
         * @param [callback] Called after the worklog is added.
         * @return {P

romise} Resolved after the worklog is added.
     */
    this.addWorkLog = function (opts, callback) {
        if (!opts.worklog) {
            throw new Error(errorStrings.NO_WORKLOG_ERROR);
        }
        var options = this.buildRequestOptions(opts, '/worklog', 'POST', opts.worklog, {
            newEstimate: opts.newEstimate,
            reduceBy: opts.reduceBy,
            adjustEstimate: opts.adjustEstimate
        });

        return this.jiraClient.makeRequest(options, callback, 'Worklog Added');
    };
```

Under getoAuth() I am doing my oAuth authentification, and I want to add the worklog to the Issue NTS-4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I am sending the input directly via REST Call (POST). For that, I am using 'request'

```
function updateIssueInJira(oauth)
{

var testjson = {
    author: {
        emailAddress: "myemail"
    },
    comment: "Test",
    timeSpentSeconds: "2700"
}
request.post({
    url:'https://thelocation.com/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUEKEY/worklog/',
    oauth:oauth,  
    json:true,
    body: testjson
}, 
    function (e, r, user) {
    console.log(user)
});
}
```